# Common ground between two power supply

Tags: power-supply, dc-motor, esp8266

I've tried to use a motor driver module(hg7881) with the esp8266. The esp8266 was connected to a 3.3v breadboard power supply and the DC motor with a different one, a 9.6v NiMh battery pack. I've shared the two power supply GND but after a while the esp8266 get hot and stopped work. What went wrong? Maybe because the different voltage of the two power supply?
Edit:
I've tried same setting but instead of use the NiMh battery had used a wall DC power supply and it's working well.

Comment: Any kind of schematic?  Just '...used a motor driver module with...' doesn't say how you have anything hooked up.

Answer (score 1):

Your motor + driver module are working on 9.6 V
Your esp8266 is working on 3.3 V
Grounds are common, that is how it should be :-)

The signals from the esp8266 are between 0 and 3.3 V as that is the
power supply of this circuit.

The motor driver should be able to work with that 3.3V signal (could not find a proper datasheet of the chips on this board).

I hope you did NOT connect the Vcc connection of the motor driver to the Vcc of the esp8266 because then the esp8266 would get 9.6 V supply and that could fry it almost instantly.

Before you try again with a new esp8266, place 1 kohm resistors between the outputs of the esp8266 and the inputs of the motor driver, that way at least nothing should break.